# Что значит += в коде програмы на Руби?

Tags: ruby, синтаксис

Что значит `+=` в коде на Руби? Например:

```
number_turns += 1
```

Comment: @Timofey Bondarev, почему тэг "синтаксис" убрали?

Comment: @Nakilon Метка "синтаксис" очень похожа на [мета-метку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Проблема усугубляется тем, что у неё нет описания, и из-за этого проверка правильности её использования затруднена.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev, 1) вопрос может иметь только этот тэг, если вопрос языко-агностичен 2) этот тэг не двусмысленен 3) этот тэг [есть на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax)

Comment: @Nakilon Да, пожалуй согласен с 1 и 2. 3 не считаю сильным аргументом. Вернул метку. Предлагаю удалить наши комментарии, чтобы не захлямлять вопрос, так как они не относятся напрямую к теме вопроса.

Comment: Только вот смысл выражения "что значит?" в данном случае скорее относится не к *синтаксису*, а к *семантике*. Так что тэг *синтаксис* тут сомнителен.

Answer (score 5):

В любом языке программирования (по крайней мере я не встречал иного) данный оператор `+=`, как в примере,

```
number_turns+=1
```

называется составным оператором присваивания и эквивалентен

```
number_turns = number_turns + 1
```

Просто первая запись является сокращением второй записи.

Comment: Всё так. Более того, в руби `+=` реально разворачивается в указанную запись, отдельного оператора `+=` в рантайме уже не существует. И чтобы получить для собственного класса `+=`, достаточно реализовать `+`.

Comment: @D-side, "уже" -- это с какой версии?

Comment: @Nakilon "уже" это после разбора парсером и компанией в байткод.

Comment: Если кому-то интересно, [пруф на IDEone](http://ideone.com/An6QCh), у них там Ruby 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

```
number_turns += 1
number_turns = number_turns + 1
```

Оба одинаковы, но первый вариант короче и удобнее.
Кроме единицы можно использовать любое другое число или функцию.
Также прошу заметить, что кроме (+=) есть ещё (-=), (*=), (/=), (%=); не знаю как у руби, но в питоне ещё есть (//=), что означает целочисленное деление. В плюсах так же побитовые есть (^=), (&=) и тд. Я, надеюсь, суть вы уловили?

Comment: Большое Спасибо! Я еще многго не знаю, но учусь:)

Comment: В Ruby есть ещё шедевральный `||=`, который, несмотря на сходство, работает чуть иначе. `a ||= b` эквивалентен `a || a = b`. Так что запомнить правило стоит, но есть и исключения.

Comment: @D-side, это не исключение. `a ||= b` эквивалентно `a = a || b`. В этом случае, если `a` уже назначена, то ничего произойдёт, если же  `a == nil`, то ей будет присвоено значение `b`

Comment: @Василиса ваше же объяснение противоречит вашей записи. Не "ничего [не] произойдёт", а в `a` будет присвоено значение из `a` же. Для локальных переменных разницы не будет, а вот для методов и доступа по ключу (`[]`/`[]=`) разница [очень даже будет](https://ideone.com/MJzGcJ).

Comment: @D-side, и снова спасибо, одним заблуждением в руби у меня стало меньше. Отдельное спасибо за объяснение с примером конкретного кода. Ещё вот [здесь](http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html) есть очень подробная (хотя и весьма не новая) статья с кучей примеров